# Best practice with custom restful routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my web-app I have a typical User-Activation process by e-Mail.

At the moment I have a custom controller action for each step in the activation process, i.e. I've got an action "activate" that more or less simply renders the "register"-page, then I have another action "activation" which is the target action of the actual form on the register page.

I wonder if this is best practice? - right now, I'm on the verge of implementing admin-initiated password resets (admin clicks a link for a password reset on a specific user, the user gets an email with a link to a page where he can set a new password). I would go further, and add 3 more controller actions (one for sending the reset-email, one for the user accessing the reset-page, and one for the action of the actual reset-form).

This seems to clutter up my controller quite a bit and I wonder if this was the "right" way to do it?

thx for any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is fine - it is not necessary to conform your controller actions to the RESTful actions.  REST should only be used if it fits your model, but you shouldn't try to make your model conform to a RESTful architecture unless it makes the interaction easier and intuitive.

It might be best to place these custom actions into their own controllers though, rather than the UsersController. Once you feel that your controller is getting too crowded, it's probably a good idea to move some actions into separate modules or controllers of their own.

```
class RegistrationController
  def activate # perform the activation
    ..
  end

  def activation # show the activation page
    ...
  end
end

class PasswordController
  def send # send the email
  end

  def resetter # show the page to reset the password
  end

  def reset # actually reset the password
  end
end
```

These controller actions could be accessed via custom routes instead of resources.

```
match 'register/activation' => 'registration#activation'
post 'register/activate' => 'registration#activate'

post 'password/send' => 'password#send'
match 'password/resetter' => 'password#resetter'
post 'password/reset' => 'password#reset'
```

Comment: thx, this seems a lot cleaner than my current way of doing it